# Cannot get file by its name, if file has cyrillic chracters in it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So the problem is:

Method **getFilesByName()** return nothing if i target file with cyrillic. But i can see this file if i use **getName()**.

Where is the problem?

**Added:**

Sorry for dissapear. As the second comments says - the problem stays if filename got uppercase letters.

So, if i try to search list of files in target folder, googlescript will see my file, and return "Шаблон по описанию".

```
function checkFile2(){
  var foldername = "CaseMe";
  var filename = FILE_NAME;

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);

  Logger.log(folder.hasNext());

  //Folder does not exist
  if(!folder.hasNext()){

  Logger.log("No Folder Found");

  }
  //Folder does exist
  else{
    Logger.log("Folder Found")
    var file   = folder.next().getFiles;
    if(!file.hasNext()){
       Logger.log("No Files Found");
    }
    else{
      while (file.hasNext()) {
      var filel = file.next();
      Logger.log(filel.getName());

    }
  }

}
```

But, if i will try to search by target name

```
function checkFile2(){
  var foldername = "CaseMe";
  var filename = FILE_NAME; // return "Шаблон по описанию"

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);

  Logger.log(folder.hasNext());

  //Folder does not exist
  if(!folder.hasNext()){

  Logger.log("No Folder Found");

  }
  //Folder does exist
  else{
    Logger.log("Folder Found")
    var file   = folder.next().getFilesByName(filename + '.xml');
    if(!file.hasNext()){
       Logger.log("No File Found");
    }
    else{
      Logger.log("Files Found"); 
    }
  }
}
```

Googlescritp won't find my file and will return "No File Found"

Comment: When you're using the getName() method, does the script give you the name on cyrillic ?

Answer (score 1):

It does work, I think you don't quite understand the `.getFilesByName()` method.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename) shows that this method returns a collection of all files in the user's Drive that have the given name. I.e. it returns an object as can be seen in the screenshot below, you must then use the `.hasNext()` and `.next()` methods to iterate through the object.

The screenshot below should make it a little clearer. I created 3 test files of the same name (copied the characters from Wikipedia).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem stays on, if the file name contains uppercase letters.

```
function startFindFile() {

      var folder =  DriveApp.getFolderById(DriveApp.getFoldersByName("prices").next().getId()); 
      var fileNameCyr1 = "Прайс1_Склад ЦС.xls";
      var fileNameCyr2 = "прайс1_склад цс.xls";
      var fileNameEng = "Price.txt";

      Logger.log("List all files:" );
      var files = folder.getFiles();
      findFile(files);

      Logger.log("Find files: " + fileNameEng ); 
      files = folder.getFilesByName(fileNameEng);
      findFile(files);

      Logger.log("Find files: " + fileNameCyr1 ); 
      files = folder.getFilesByName(fileNameCyr1);
      findFile(files);

      Logger.log("Find files: " + fileNameCyr2 );
      files = folder.getFilesByName(fileNameCyr2);
      findFile(files);
    }

    function findFile(files) {

       while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        Logger.log(file.getName() + " " + file.getId());

       }

    }
```

[Result from Logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU7SC.jpg)